# Como chamar método de classe em outro app?

Tags: python, django

Quero criar um arquivo chamado `config.py` e colocar algumas configurações dentro de um dicionário para sempre que precisar invocar esses parâmetros.

Mas como eu chamo esse parâmetro no Python?

Por exemplo, vou criar a classe `Config`.

```
class Config:

@classmethod
def getConfig(self):
    parameters = {
        'url_m'                 : 'domain',
        'url_ws_m'              : 'domain.api',
        'url_get_token'         : 'domain.token',
        'url_external_access'   : 'external',
        'name_ws_m'             : 'service'
    }

    return parameters
```

No outro app fiz assim:

```
from pp.core.Config import *
.
.
.
a = Config().getConfig()['url_m']
```

Assim funcionou.
Mas existe um método mais elegante de importar a classe com o método ou esse é o jeito mais correto mesmo?

Comment: Onde tem esse config.py?

Comment: Eu criei numa pasta.

Comment: Criou onde? Na raiz? dentro da `main app`? dentro de outra app? Talvez ajudasse se colocasse a estrutura como está agora

Comment: Criei dentro da pasta core dentro da pasta principal do projeto.

Comment: Seria legal se você usasse o configparser: https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dá pra ficar mais simples e elegante sim. Use o módulo apenas e crie uma função que dê acesso a um dicionário interno do módulo. Ex:

Arquivo "Config.py"

```
_parameters = {
    'url_m'                 : 'domain',
    'url_ws_m'              : 'domain.api',
    'url_get_token'         : 'domain.token',
    'url_external_access'   : 'external',
    'name_ws_m'             : 'service'
}

def get(key):
    return _parameters[key]
```

E para usar, chame assim:

```
import pp.core.Config as Config

a = Config.get('url_m')
```

A classe, no teu caso, está apenas colocando uma camada de complexidade que vc não precisa.

Comment: Na verdade, esse seu método get também é uma "camada que não é precisa": o dicionário definido no módulo pode ser usado diretamente.

Comment: Como faria isso @jsbueno?

Comment: Fica elegante mesmo Eric. Eu conheço esses recursos, mas não lembro de usar.

Comment: Por que sua variável começa com underscore? Eu venho do PHP, então estou acostumado com camelCase...

Comment: "Como faria isso @jsbueno?" - simplesmente importe diretamente a variável no módulo em que for usar as configurações, em vez de importar a função `get` e use-a. O "_" no prefixo também não é necessário.

Comment: O underscore é uma convenção do python para dizer que aquela variável não deve ser usada globalmente. Se vc realmente quiser usar nada te impede. Mas a convenção fica aí como lembrete.

Comment: Sim. A função get não é realmente necessária. Eu poderia dar um `from Config import parameters` (nesse caso eu faria sem underscore) e simplesmente usar `parameters['myKey']`. Porém eu quis fazer um exemplo mais próximo de os parâmetros serem read only. É uma questão de preferência pessoal. O proprio settings.py do django usa essa semantica de dicionário em que os parâmetros podem ser alterados em runtime. O jeito que eu pus é só uma maneira de fazer. Não a única.

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa criar uma class pra isso. Você pode criar um arquivo config.py com um dicicionario e depois importar esse dicionário onde deseja usar.

No arquivo config.py

```
parameters = {
    'url_m'                 : 'domain',
    'url_ws_m'              : 'domain.api',
    'url_get_token'         : 'domain.token',
    'url_external_access'   : 'external',
    'name_ws_m'             : 'service'
}
```

E no foo.py

```
from config import parameters

a = parameters['url_m']
```